# Is there a way to check DNS cache on an Android device?

Tags: cache, dns

Is there a way to check DNS cache on an Android device? For example, you can check it on windows via the command `ipconfig /displaydns`.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: If you do not tell us, we may vote to close your question.

Comment: Never mind.  I found [a post somewhere else](http://superuser.com/questions/230308/explain-output-of-ipconfig-displaydns#230311) which explains why checking the DNS cache can be useful.

Comment: Why does every time someone asks a question, someone responds with, "Why do you want to do this?"  The WHY is irrelevant: the question is posted.  Answer it if you can, or don't.  I personally want to know because it pertains to a DNS caching issue I'm researching.  Does that help answer your question?  Of course it doesn't--the why is irrelevant.